BERT (bit error rate test with ADC )
I'm trying to make a digital decoder. I sampled a digitally modulated signal with the LTC2387, an 18-bit 15MHz SAR ADC. The carrier signal is at 2.1MHz, and is digitally mixed down to DC to obtain the IQ samples. After that, decimation is peformed. The ADC has a dynamic range of 95dBFS, and then I conduct a BERT (bit error rate test). For some reason, errors start occurring when the signal is at -106dBFS.
This doesn't make any sense since I only have 95dBFS of dynamic range. I suspect that performing decimation might help, but I'm not sure. I hope someone can provide an explanation.
